# change JDK version in octave on mac

Tags: java, macos, octave

Octave 3.8.2, OS X 10.10.4

I used

```
ml_jar_version=javaMethod('getProperty','java.lang.System','java.version');
ml_jar_version=['Java ' ml_jar_version];
```

to check the java version and I got

```
ml_jar_version = Java 1.6.0_65
```

However, I want Octave to use JDK 1.7 and so I typed

```
setenv("JAVA_HOME","/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home");
```

but `ml_jar_version` did not change.

**My question** is: how to make Octave to use JDK 1.7?

**Edit 1**: my Octave was installed through homebrew. I believe homebrew just downloaded precompiled binaries. The following is the configuration of my Octave installation:

```
homebrew/science/octave: stable 3.8.2 (bottled), HEAD
a high-level interpreted language for numerical computations.
https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/index.html
/usr/local/Cellar/octave/3.8.2_1 (2111 files, 54M)
  Poured from bottle
/usr/local/Cellar/octave/3.8.2_2 (2111 files, 54M) *
  Poured from bottle
From: https://github.com/homebrew/homebrew-science/blob/master/octave.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: pkg-config ✔, gnu-sed ✘
Required: pcre ✔, qscintilla2 ✔, qt ✔, pstoedit ✔
Recommended: gnuplot ✔, suite-sparse421 ✔, readline ✔, arpack ✔, fftw ✔, glpk ✔, gl2ps ✔, graphicsmagick ✔, hdf5 ✔, qhull ✔, qrupdate ✔, epstool ✔, ghostscript ✔
Optional: openblas ✘
==> Options
--with-jit
    Use the experimental JIT support (not recommended)
--with-native-graphics
    Use native OpenGL/FLTKgraphics (does not work with the GUI)
--with-openblas
    Use OpenBLAS instead of native LAPACK/BLAS
--without-arpack
    Build without arpack support
--without-check
    Skip build-time tests (not recommended)
--without-curl
    Do not use cURL (urlread/urlwrite/@ftp)
--without-docs
    Don't build documentation
--without-epstool
    Build without epstool support
--without-fftw
    Do not use FFTW (fft,ifft,fft2,etc.)
--without-ghostscript
    Build without ghostscript support
--without-gl2ps
    Build without gl2ps support
--without-glpk
    Do not use GLPK
--without-gnuplot
    Do not use gnuplot graphics
--without-graphicsmagick
    Build without graphicsmagick support
--without-gui
    Do not build the experimental GUI
--without-hdf5
    Do not use HDF5 (hdf5 data file support)
--without-java
    Build without java support
--without-qhull
    Do not use the Qhull library (delaunay,voronoi,etc.)
--without-qrupdate
    Do not use the QRupdate package (qrdelete,qrinsert,qrshift,qrupdate)
--without-readline
    Build without readline support
--without-suite-sparse421
    Do not use SuiteSparse (sparse matrix operations)
--without-zlib
    Do not use zlib (compressed MATLAB file formats)
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
```

Comment: How did you install octave? Have you compiled it yourself? How? Have you used a binary installer? Which?

Comment: @LudwigSchulze, I installed Octave through homebrew. For details please refer to my Edit 1.

Comment: Trying to reproduce homebrew octave installation I run into an error: brew tap homebrew/science; brew update; brew install octave -> error when installing a dependency "suite-sparse": 404 for http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/SuiteSparse/SuiteSparse-3.7.0.tar.gz

Comment: Even after replacing that URL in the formula with a valid one AND disabling the MD5 sum check in that formula, compilation of this dependency fails with --->Error: inreplace failed
UFconfig/UFconfig.mk:
  expected to change "CC" to "clang"
  expected to change "CFLAGS" to nil
  expected to change "CPLUSPLUS" to "clang++"<---

Comment: @LudwigSchulze, thanks for your effort. I just upgraded suite-sparse and compilation was not needed at all... strange...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that octave reads the symbolic link 'dafault-java', here:
/usr/lib/jvm/default-java

```
$ls -al

drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 нов 19 21:37 .
drwxr-xr-x 181 root root 12288 нов 19 20:45 ..
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    14 нов 19 21:37 default-java -> java-8-openjdk-amd64/
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    20 апр 23  2016 java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64 -> java-8-openjdk-amd64
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  2600 окт 27 21:06 .java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64.jinfo
drwxr-xr-x   8 root root  4096 нов 19 20:45 java-7-oracle
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  2543 нов 19 20:45 .java-7-oracle.jinfo
drwxr-xr-x   7 root root  4096 нов 19 21:37 java-8-openjdk-amd64
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 нов 16 20:28 openjdk-8
```

You need to change it to point to your java folder :

First remove it:

```
$sudo rm default-java
```

Then make a new symbolic link (java-7-oracle in my case):

```
$ln -s java-7-oracle/ default-java
```

It shoud work afterwards.

In octave:

```
>> javaMethod('getProperty','java.lang.System','java.version')
ans = 1.7.0_80
```